# Pipe two log generating programs in parallel into one python program

Tags: bash, pipe

I have two identical programs which generate logs indefinitely until they are terminated. The current iteration of my bash program pipes one of these log-generating programs into a python program which processes the logs real-time:

```
./log1 | python program.py
```

I now want to add the second log program, "log2", into the pipe so as both feed their logs into program.py. I have tried grouping the two into one as in:

```
{ ./log1; ./log2; } | python program.py
```

But this will only pipe log1 into program.py as log1 never ends. I need both logs to send their data to program.py like:

1. log1 data > program.py
2. log2 data > program.py
3. log1 data > program.py
4. log1 data > program.py
5. log2 data > program.py
6. etc.

Basically program.py just accepts the latest stdout into its stdin concurrently. If anyone has any ideas that would be great.

Comment: You could use a process-substitution(`<()`) to pass the command's output to another program as if it were read from a file `python program.py <(./log1) <(./log2)`

When you use the construct `<(..)`, it is replaced with a pathname of a temporary file that is connected to the standard output of the command inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could create a script which runs `log1` and `log2` in the background, and then pipe that to `program.py`

For example, a script called `all_logs.bash`:

```
./log1 &
./log2 &
wait # waits for all background processes to finish
```

And then run:

```
./all_logs.bash | program.py
```

Make sure you make `all_logs.bash` executable.

---

**Example**

Testing this with the following seems to work:

```
# all_logs.bash
(for n in $(seq 5); do echo a$n; sleep 0.9; done) &
(for n in $(seq 5); do echo b$n; sleep 0.6; done) &
wait
```

And:

```
# stdin_test.py
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

while True:
    data = sys.stdin.readline()
    if data:
        print('data: {}'.format(data), end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
    else:
        break

print('Done.')
```

Outputs the following:

```
$ ./all_logs.bash | python stdin_test.py
data: a1
data: b1
data: b2
data: a2
data: b3
data: a3
data: b4
data: b5
data: a4
data: a5
Done.
```

Comment: all_logs.bash works great when run by itself but for some reason when I pipe all_logs.bash into program.py, it reverts to only expressing one of the logs at a time.

Comment: It works with my makeshift python program. What version of python are you using? And what does you `program.py` do? Maybe one is outputting to stderr? Try: `./all_logs.bash 2>&1 | program.py`

Comment: I am trying some test programs that are easier to see whats happening. I am using 2 python programs as the inputs which just write to stdout the numbers 1 - 30 in series with a short wait in between numbers. If the numbers are jumbled I judge them to be running synchronously. My program.py just reads from stdin and outputs the current value. Maybe if you posted the programs you are using to test it would give me a better idea of how to do it. =)

Comment: I have added my tests to my answer. Please review and see how this compares. You can even try copying and pasting my solutions to ensure this works with your OS/Python/BASH versions.

Comment: Have had luck using the date command as was in your programs, but changing from date to another command, for example "seq 5" no longer works. Was thinking that maybe the pipe causes the commands to run in sequence as program.py relies on the immediate input of the first log program. If so, I don't understand why date would work still.

Comment: My command is `date; sleep 1; date` which takes 1 second to run. `seq 5` will run immediately. If you make a loop so it takes longer to run then you'll see the output is merged.

Comment: I have modified my answer to use `seq`.